# properties in ComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

Why i cant set selecteditem property programatically?

Im calling it from another XAML Window, that hace certaing controls , one of them is a ComboBox i was trying this :

```
            string tm = (from ea in db.EXAMENXATENCIONs where ea.codigo == Convert.ToInt32(numeroinforme) select ea.turnomedico).FirstOrDefault();
            demo.cboTurnoMed.SelectedItem  = tm;
            demo.cboTurnoMed.Text =  tm;
```

C# 3.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the item you're trying to set as selected well in the `ComboBox` data source?
The `SelectedItem` property looks for the value you provide in data source and then select it if found.

Comment: What's showing null? The ComboBox.SelectedItem?
I mean, have you added the item in ComboBox.Items collection before trying to set it as SelectedItem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what type of object your ComboBox has in it, but you might try setting the SelectedValue rather than the SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the SelectedItem. But the objects must MATCH. They can't just have the same data, they must actually be the same object.

What you're doing when you set the SelectItem property is saying, "You (the combobox) have a collection of  objects, and I want this particular one in your list to be the selected one". You are not actually giving the combobox a new item, if that clears it up.